# Need help for Cross Tab SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

This is the source example table:

```
    UserID  UserNameType    UserName
    1       First Name      FN1
    1       Last Name       LN1
    2       First Name      FN2
    2       Last Name       LN2
    3       First Name      FN3
    3       Last Name       LN3
    4       First Name      FN4
    4       Last Name       LN4
```

I would like to have a SQL query to display my result like the given format below.

```
   
    UserID  FirstName   LastName
    1       FN1         LN1
    2       FN2         LN2
    3       FN3         LN3
    4       FN4         LN4
```

Need a little more help on this...

[image: Need Help]

Thanks,
Yugal

Comment: Personally I would redesign as this is a very poor design choice which will cause some major performance issues over time. Google the problems of using an EAV table.

Comment: Hi HLGEM, I had just given an example of what kind of data I have and out of which what I am expecting some result set.<br> Please refer the attached image of actual problem. <br> I have tried the solution suggested by Dems, but its not working out for the actual problem. Thanks</br>Yugal

Comment: HI All,
Solution suggested by mellamokb worked here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple cross-tab method (which I personally prefer) is to use the group by operator with MAX(CASE WHEN...) pattern to control the cross-tab fields.  This is easy to understand IMO and easy to extend with more fields.  I'm not sure about the performance.

```
select
    UserID,
    max(case when usernametype='First Name' then username end) as FirstName,
    max(case when usernametype='Last Name' then username end) as LastName
from
    MyTable T
group by
    UserID
```

Comment: +1 : For two fields I'd join, as a general solution for `n` fields, this is exactly the way I'd go.  (Though if there are many Attribute Types, I'd filter them down to just the ones I'm using, in the WHERE clause.)

Comment: Thanks mellamokb,
Finally I got the solution...

Thanks,
Yugal

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  [fn].UserID,
  [fn].UserName,
  [ln].UserName
FROM
  yourTable AS [fn]
INNER JOIN
  yourTable AS [ln]
    ON [fn].UserID = [ln].UserID
WHERE
      [fn].UserNameType = 'FirstName'
  AND [ln].UserNameType = 'LastName'
```

Comment: Hi Dems, Your query worked for the mentioned User table but, I need a little more help on a similar type of table structure, please have a look at the attached image.

Comment: When I am applying your query in the table given here, it's duplicating the result set.

Comment: Dems, I have attached an image of actual problem, below the Question asked initially. its related to doctype and docname.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but I can't see any image, or any links to images...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery

```
SELECT 
    UserID,
    UserName as FirstName,
    (SELECT top 1 UserName 
     FROM myTable 
     WHERE UserID = t.UserID 
     and UserNameType = 'Last Name') as LastName
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.UserNameType = 'First Name'
```

Comment: Either will work, only testing will reveal which one will work better for this situation

Answer (score 1):

To avoid subqueries and the speed penalties that can arise form them, just join yourself.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 T1.UserID UserID, 
 T1.UserName FirstName, 
 T2.UserName LastName
FROM 
 Users T1 JOIN Users T2 
  ON T1.UserID = T2.userID
WHERE 
 T1.UserNameType = 'FirstName'
 AND T2.UserNameType = 'LastName'
```

EDIT: Should be fixed now.

Comment: This will give each UserID twice, and once will have the FirstName and LastName fields back to front.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have following table

```
create table #temp1
(
    UserID  int,
    usernametype varchar(10),
    username varchar(10)
)
```

Following are the inserts

```
insert into #temp1(userid, usernametype, username) valueS(1, 'First Name', 'FN1')
insert into #temp1(userid, usernametype, username) valueS(1, 'Last Name', 'LN1')
insert into #temp1(userid, usernametype, username) valueS(2, 'First Name', 'FN2')
insert into #temp1(userid, usernametype, username) valueS(2, 'Last Name', 'LN2')
insert into #temp1(userid, usernametype, username) valueS(3, 'First Name', 'FN3')
insert into #temp1(userid, usernametype, username) valueS(3, 'Last Name', 'LN3')
insert into #temp1(userid, usernametype, username) valueS(4, 'First Name', 'FN4')
insert into #temp1(userid, usernametype, username) valueS(4, 'Last Name', 'LN4')
```

[image]

SQl Query

```
SELECT  userid, [First Name], [Last Name]
FROM    
( 
    SELECT userid, usernametype, username FROM #temp1
) 
p 
PIVOT 
( 
    Max(username) FOR usernametype 
    IN ([First Name], [Last Name])
) AS pvt
```

Final Result set

[image]

Comment: Did u try this in your query window?:) Not scary as much u described :)

Comment: I think, it's better then sub query (behaves like loop for each record)

Comment: plz. Check the query cost as well .

Comment: Table scan is 50% less comparing your's. FYI and in case of missing non Clustered Index. Just imagine what if i implement it. Reason is your Sub Query

Comment: It never fails to amaze me that I forget that PIVOT has existed so long.  But now I recall, there Is a reason I've sometimes Had to avoid it...  *If the pivotted fields legitimately all contain NULL values, PIVOT strips them out of the result set.  What a git :(*  But it's exactly what is needed here, so it gets my vote :)

Comment: I've tried using your query also, but it's not working for my actual problem, can you please re-consider my query?. Thanks.

Comment: It works fine for the original post. Please review the comments posted by Dems  for your original post help.